# iOS. Parse & Run Objective-C code from text file

Tags: ios, objective-c, parsing, runtime

I would like to know, is it possible to parse a text file that contains objective-c code and execute this code into runtime in iOS-application?

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not, at least as long as you want to deploy on the AppStore. The best chance for you to get such behaviour would be using JavaScript inside a `UIWebView`.

Have a look at `UIWebView`'s `stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString`